# rdp plugin has some problem! I can not work by remmina

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, rdp

I want to use a remote desktop so I choose remmina but when I run it I have a problem like:

```
Failed to load plugin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/remmina/plugins/remmina-plugin-rdp.so.
Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreerdp-client2.so.2: undefined symbol: msusb_msconfig_read
The glibsecret secret plugin  has been initialized and it will be your default secret plugin
```

Can you tell me how can I solve it. I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and remmina 1.4.16

Comment: I use Remmina 1.4.16 on Ubuntu 18.0.4 too, but I works. How did you install remmina? Did you do it by SNAP?

Comment: It was installed on my system by default

Comment: Did you try with `sudo apt install --reinstall remmina`?

Comment: No I didn't but I used commands and ppa for updating it. Do you suggest I reinstall it?